# How to increment through a list and replace certain values with their counts

Tags: python

I'm trying to increment through a list and replace multiple occurrences (in sequence) of a given value with the amount of times they occurred (as a rough range, with occurrences of 1-3 being small, 4-6 being medium, and more than 6 being a large amount of times).

I am trying to find an elegant solution to this problem and hoping for any guidance. I looked through itertools but couldn't find something suitable for this (I think).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

So for instance:

testList = [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]

will become

[1, "2 small amount of times", 1, 1, "2 small amount of times", 1, 4, 1, "2 medium amount of times", 1, "2 large amount of times"]

```
testList = [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]

listLocation = -1

newlist = []

for i in testList:

    listLocation += 1

    if i == 2:

        if testList[listLocation+1] == 2:

            testList[listLocation] = "2 multiple"

            newlist.append(testList[listLocation])

            testList.pop(listLocation+1)

    else:
        newlist.append(i)

newlist
```

This is as far as I've gotten, right now this just detects when 2 occurs multiple times in sequence and replaces that sequence with a string, but I can't work out how to move from this to an actual counter that bins it by ranges and a more elegant style of code (I'm sure there is a way to avoid having the listLocation variable to keep track of list index). Also I can't work out how to detect the end of the list because right now this will crash if it hits a 2 as the last value in the list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: You mean "iterate through a list". "Increment" would give you `[2,3,3,2,...]` Anyway what you're looking for here is called **run-length encoding**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution. First, let's define a function which returns a message to be inserted into the list:

```
def message(value, count):
    msg = '{value} {amount} amount of times'

    if 1 <= count <= 3:
        msg = msg.format(value=value, amount='small')
    elif 4 <= count <= 6:
        msg = msg.format(value=value, amount='medium')
    else:
        msg = msg.format(value=value, amount='large')

    return msg
```

Second, we define a function which takes a list of values and a value to be counted as its arguments:

```
def counter(values, value):
    count = 0
    results = []

    for i, v in enumerate(values):

        if v != value:

            if count:
                results.append(message(value, count))
                count = 0

            results.append(v)
            continue

        count = count + 1

        if i < len(values) - 1:
            continue

        results.append(message(value, count))

    return results
```

Here is the result:

```
>>> values = [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]
>>> counter(values, value=2)
[1,
 '2 small amount of times',
 1,
 1,
 '2 small amount of times',
 1,
 4,
 1,
 '2 medium amount of times',
 1,
 '2 large amount of times',
 1]
```

Comment: This is a fantastic and elegant solution thank you constt.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think is a simple way to do it.

```py
a = [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]
b = []
i=0
while  i<len(a) and i < len(a):
    if a[i]==2:
        n=i
        while a[i]==2:
            i+=1

        if (i-n)<4:
            b.append("2 small amount of times")
        elif (i-n)<6 and (i-n)>4:
            b.append("2 medium amount of times")
        else:
            b.append("2 large amount of times")                                                                                                                

    else:
        b.append(a[i])
        i+=1
print(b)
```

Outputs:

```
[1, '2 small amount of times', 1, 1, '2 small amount of times', 1, 4, 1, '2 large amount of times', 1, '2 large amount of times', 1]
```

Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: No problem! If this helped, kindly accept the answer!

Comment: Quick query = this only works on lists that don't end in 2. If you try running a = [1, 2, 2] it won't work and has an index error.

Comment: Also if you run, a = [1, 2, 2, 2, 5], it should come out as a medium amount of times, but it comes out as a large amount of times for some reason, any help on this would be appreciated thanks Haran